# Accomplish transclusion with ng-metadata

Tags: angularjs, angular-upgrade

I am using AngularJs 1.6 with ng-metadata to progressively migrate the AngularJS components to Angular.

I need to build a component that is able to transclude a bit of HTML and I was hoping I can use something provided by ng-metadata since it will be easier when we upgrade to Angular. Unfortunately I can't find anything in the docs about this.

An example of a AngularJS component written using ng-metadata that uses transclusion will help me get started with this.

Comment: Can't you just add `transclude: true` to your component?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Apparently this works: legacy: { transclude: true},

Comment: Good to hear! I've added an answer to this post based on my comment.

Answer (score 2):

This is how my component decorator ended up looking.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'diDropdown',
    templateUrl: require('./dropdown-component.html'),
    legacy: { transclude: true},
})
export class DropdownComponent {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable transclusion for AngularJS by adding `transclude: true`:

```
app.component('myComponent', function() {
    transclude: true,
    controller: function() {
        // Your code
    }
})
```

[Documentation on regular transclusion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude)

---

In your case, with the `ng-metadata` syntax, use:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'myComponent',
    templateUrl: 'my-template.html',
    legacy: {
        transclude: true
    }
})
```

[More info about ng-metadata's transclusion](http://jongear.io/ng-metadata-answer-upgrading-angular-2/)

Comment: Yes, that is how to do it in AngularJs, however I want to use the ng-metadata syntax.

Comment: Updated answer.